# Finding IP address of an FTP account before DNS is updated

Tags: vps, ip-address

Ive gone through serverfault.com for various similar questions, but couldnt find the relevant one. I am at sixes and sevens with regards to server relate stuff.

So my client have a vps and already have like `5-10 domains` in that. And i create a new site for him and his server guys created an ftp account and send me the details.

I access the cpanel through `http://10.10.10.10/cpanel` and i can upload everything, configure database and all.

But when i go to `http://10.10.10.10/` i see its going to somewhere else.

So what i am asking is that, whether i can know the correct url/ip address through which i can see the site through browsers, can be obtained from the cPanel? The reason for not updating the DNS is that, client wants to test the working of the new site fully before moving from old site.

IP has been changed for privacy.

Answer (score 1):

The typical solution if you want to test a website on a new server when the DNS hasn't been updated yet is to add en entry to the `hosts` file on your workstation.

```
  #/etc/hosts on Linux UNIX BSD
  # %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts on Windows
  # <ip-address>  <hostname>
  127.0.0.1 localhost
  10.10.10.10 www.my-new-website.com
```

Answer (score 0):

After lot of search in google, found the answer :

Simply use :

```
http://<SERVER_IP>/~CPANELUSERNAME
```

Source : http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/see-hosted-website-before-dns-changes-335971.html